# Add class to a link when clicking it and remove it when clicking elsewhere

Tags: html, css, typescript

***Important***: I tried many solutions here and none of them worked for me.

I have a dropdown list, I want to add it a CSS class when I hover or click it, and remove it when click somewhere else.

```css
a.linkOnMouseDropDown:hover /*work fine */
{
  background-color: rgb(220, 234, 255) !important;
  color: rgb(21, 96, 143);
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.linkOnMouseDropDown:focus /*not work*/
{
  background-color: rgb(220, 234, 255);
  color: rgb(21, 96, 143);
}

a.linkOnMouseDropDown:not(:focus) /*not work */
{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

a.dropDownOption:hover //work fine
{
  background-color: rgb(25, 99, 112) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li appDropdown>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle linkOnMouseDropDown" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropDownOption">Save Data</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropDownOption">Fetch Data</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Again: 
I need the 'Manage' dropdown will be changed when the user is hovering or click it according to :

```
   a.linkOnMouseDropDown:hover
```

And remove it when I click somewhere else.

Many thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, its based on my own directive (Angular):

```
@Directive({
    selector:'[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) toggleOpen(event: Event) 
    {
      this.isOpen = this.elRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ? !this.isOpen : false; 
      this.headerservice.isDropdownOpen.next(this.isOpen); //I added this line!

    }
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
                private headerservice: HeaderService) {}  
}
```

And my Service class:

```
export class HeaderService{

    isDropdownOpen = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

I using a flag, but I also must listen to it all the time, so I added the subject in the Service. Now I listen to it in the header component:

```
export class headerComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
    collapsed = true;
    linkPressed = "";
    subscription: Subscription;
    dropdownClicked=false;

    constructor(private headerservice: HeaderService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscription = this.headerservice.isDropdownOpen.subscribe(
        (state: boolean) =>{
          this.dropdownClicked = state;
      }
      );

    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}


<ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <li class="" appDropdown>
                <a  class="dropdown-toggle linkOnMouseHover" [ngClass]="{customBackground:dropdownClicked}" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a  class="dropDownOption" >Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a  class="dropDownOption" >Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Conclusion: I had to use my directive flag. However, in the header component, there is another approach as Michael D suggested (instead of using the ngClass):

```
@ViewChild('manageButton', {static: false}) manageButton: any;
```

And in the subscribe function:

```
if(state == true){
       this.manageButton.nativeElement.classList.add('customBackground');
}else{
       this.manageButton.nativeElement.classList.remove('customBackground');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **listen to both `hover` and `click` event you can't do this with CSS alone and you should use javascript** for this purpose.

Let's say you got a `<a>` with existing class `linkOnMouseDropDown`, so whenever someone hovered on it or clicked on it, you want to a new class to it. You can handle the `hover` part with CSS alone like this:

```css
.linkOnMouseDropDown:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

But for the `click` part you should add a new event listener for `click` and whenever the target element contains `linkOnMouseDropDown` we add a new class to it called `newClass`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('linkOnMouseDropDown')) {
    e.target.classList.add('newClass');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.linkOnMouseDropDown').classList.remove('newClass');
  }
})
```

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
function addOrRemoveClass(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('linkOnMouseDropDown')) {
    e.target.classList.add('newClass');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.linkOnMouseDropDown').classList.remove('newClass');
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', addOrRemoveClass)
```

```css
.linkOnMouseDropDown:hover, .newClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li appDropdown>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle linkOnMouseDropDown" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropDownOption">Save Data</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropDownOption">Fetch Data</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### UPDATE

As you wanted a typescript solution for this you just have to handle the parameter input for your function.

So you just have to replace the js part with this:

```js
function addOrRemoveClass(e: any): void {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('linkOnMouseDropDown')) {
    e.target.classList.add('newClass');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.linkOnMouseDropDown')?.classList.remove('newClass');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', addOrRemoveClass)
```

Working demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/rNOgvoy)

Comment: @חייםחדד Since you were looking for TS solution as well, I just update the answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically assign CSS class based on `click` and `blur` events the Angular way, you could use [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) with template reference variable. Try the following

Template

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" appDropDown #r="appDropDown" >
  <button #manageButton type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle custom-button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
    Manage
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'show':r.isOpen}" >
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Here `#manageButton` is the template reference variable.

Controller

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('manageButton') manageButton: any; 

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.manageButton.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
    this.manageButton.nativeElement.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this));
  }

  onClick() {
    this.manageButton.nativeElement.classList.add('custom-background')
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.manageButton.nativeElement.classList.remove('custom-background')
  }
}
```

CSS

```css
.custom-background {
  background-color: rgb(220, 234, 255) !important;
  color:rgb(21, 96, 143) ;
}

.custom-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(220, 234, 255) !important;
  color:rgb(21, 96, 143) ;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbftfh)

Comment: Nice work, but when I click on somewhere else the 'custom-background' not been remove

Comment: It doesn`t remove the class when I click somewhere else

Comment: I think the blur doesn't fit here

Comment: Yes, you could actually work only with the `click` event here.